# Floating a div to the right causes undesirable results

Tags: html, css

I've got my code structure in the JSfiddle link below.  Problem is when I add float:right to the "Add" text it causes extra space above the "Quick Links" & "Top 20 Sites" sections.

```css
#home-content {
 padding: 5px;
}

#home-content .css-table #row1-col3 .col-body {
 padding: 5px 5px;
    /* border: 1px solid #000; */
}

/* Home page Quick Links column */
#home-content .css-table #row1-col1 .col-body > div {
    max-height: 232px;
    overflow: auto;
}

/* Home page MyShortcuts column */
#home-content .css-table #row1-col3 .col-body > div {
    max-height: 215px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.css-table {
 display: table;
 border-spacing: 9px 5px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 980px;
}

.css-table #row1-col1 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 170px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 background-color: White;
}

.css-table #row1-col2 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 540px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: White;
}

.css-table #row1-col3 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 255px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: White;
}

.css-table #row2 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 906px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: White;
}

.css-table #row2-col1 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 490px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: White;
}

.css-table #row2-col2 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 490px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: White;
}

.col-header {
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #cccccc;
 position: relative;
 height: 24px;
 padding: 7px 7px 1px 7px;
 font-family: verdana;
 font-size: 13px;
 background-color:#cccccc;
}

.col-body {
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-spacing: 1px 1px;
  font-family: verdana;
 font-size:12px;
}

.col-newsfeeds {
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 border-spacing: 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-content">
  <div class="css-table">
   <div id="row1-col1">
    <div class="col-header">
     Quick Links
   </div>
   <div class="col-body">
        Test 1
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row1-col2">
    <div class="col-header">
    Top 20 Sites
   </div>
   <div class="col-body">
        Test 2
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row1-col3">
    <div class="col-header">
     <div style="float:left;">My Shortcuts</div>
    <div style="float:right;">Add</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-body">
     Item 1<br/>
     Item 2<br/>
     Item 3<br/>
     Item 4<br/>
     Item 5<br/>
     Item 6<br/>
     Item 7<br/>
     Item 8<br/>
     Item 9<br/>
     Item 10<br/>        
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="css-table">
  <div id="row2-col1">
   <div class="col-header">
    In the News
   </div>
   <div class="col-body">
     Test 3
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row2-col2">
   <div class="col-header">
    Announcements
   </div>
   <div class="col-body">
      Test 4
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I float the "Add" text to the right of the "My Shortcuts" text without it affecting the others?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you intentionally break your fiddle link just so you did not have to post your code here? Either way, a fiddle is great but it is more important to have your code in the question.

Comment: There's no code in your question so unfortunately we can't help you. Please read [ask] and edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Dude... That's not even *that* much code.  just put it in a snippet.

Comment: Indeed, it could have been a valid question if you include the code in it. Please [edit] and click on the `<>` button in the editor, and create a stack-snippet, then I will revert my downvote and close-vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the "My Shortcuts" header to be inline-block instead of float left

```css
#home-content {
 padding: 5px;
}

#home-content .css-table #row1-col3 .col-body {
 padding: 5px 5px;
    /* border: 1px solid #000; */
}

/* Home page Quick Links column */
#home-content .css-table #row1-col1 .col-body > div {
    max-height: 232px;
    overflow: auto;
}

/* Home page MyShortcuts column */
#home-content .css-table #row1-col3 .col-body > div {
    max-height: 215px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.css-table {
 display: table;
 border-spacing: 9px 5px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 980px;
}

.css-table #row1-col1 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 170px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 background-color: White;
}

.css-table #row1-col2 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 540px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: White;
}

.css-table #row1-col3 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 255px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: White;
}

.css-table #row2 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 906px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: White;
}

.css-table #row2-col1 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 490px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: White;
}

.css-table #row2-col2 {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 490px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: White;
}

.col-header {
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #cccccc;
 position: relative;
 height: 24px;
 padding: 7px 7px 1px 7px;
 font-family: verdana;
 font-size: 13px;
 background-color:#cccccc;
}

.col-body {
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-spacing: 1px 1px;
  font-family: verdana;
 font-size:12px;
}

.col-newsfeeds {
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 border-spacing: 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-content">
  <div class="css-table">
   <div id="row1-col1">
    <div class="col-header">
     Quick Links
   </div>
   <div class="col-body">
        Test 1
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row1-col2">
    <div class="col-header">
    Top 20 Sites
   </div>
   <div class="col-body">
        Test 2
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row1-col3">
    <div class="col-header">
     <div style="display:inline-block">My Shortcuts</div>
    <div style="float:right;">Add</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-body">
     Item 1<br/>
     Item 2<br/>
     Item 3<br/>
     Item 4<br/>
     Item 5<br/>
     Item 6<br/>
     Item 7<br/>
     Item 8<br/>
     Item 9<br/>
     Item 10<br/>        
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="css-table">
  <div id="row2-col1">
   <div class="col-header">
    In the News
   </div>
   <div class="col-body">
     Test 3
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row2-col2">
   <div class="col-header">
    Announcements
   </div>
   <div class="col-body">
      Test 4
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```